# Was Catalonia ever a sovereign state?

Tags: europe, political-history, spain, catalonia

This is one question that perplexes me: Was Catalonia ever a sovereign state? I understand that Catalonia was developed out of the Frankish counties of the Marca Hispania, but it still seems disputed whether Catalonia ever had sovereignty.

Comment: Disputed by whom? Anyway, "nation" and "sovereignty" are rather more modern concepts that do not correspond easily to Medieval times.

Comment: And here I was expecting the question to be about the island of Catalonia off the coast of California. Go figure.

Answer (score 5):

As Confold remarked, a  "sovereign nation" is a modern concept that does not apply to medieval times. Since 12 to 18 century there existed a Principality of Catalonia, which was ruled by a Count of Barselona. At various times it was dependent of Aragon, Spain or France.

Answer (score 3):

Was Catalonia ever a sovereign nation? Not quite, but it has come close.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_Republic

- The Catalan Counties were de facto ruled by Barcelona and declared independence from France. They eventually merged into the Count of Aragon. Although Catalonia was sovereign, the concept of nationalism didn't really exist before the 1700s.
- The Catalan Republic declared independence in 1931 but immediately caved in to the central government.
- Revolutionary Catalonia existed from 1936 to 1939. However, revolutionary Catalonia pretended to not be a state, and only controlled part of Catalonia.